# Six letters in daily life

Tags: riddle

I've just created this riddle for you, hope you like it! :)

Clue 1:

> I can be the first like I can be the last, but I'm usually in the middle between.

Clue 2:

> I'm not the only one here, we're many.

Clue 3:

> I'm just existing in daily life, but I'm not living.

Clue 4:

> My name is composed by 6 letters.

Clue 5:

> I can be big like I can be small.

Clue 6:

> A group of me and those similar to me can be composed by at maximum 26 different types.

Clue 7:

> 325-346

**So, now try to guess who I am**

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just a suggestion: it's probably better not to call these hints. Usually "hints" are *added* to an existing self-contained puzzle, which could be solved without them, just to make it easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not it, but most clues fit:

> LETTER

I can be the first like I can be the last, but I'm usually in the middle between.

> A through Z are first and last, but most letters are in between.  (Could also be the first and last letter of a word rather than the alphabet.)

I'm not the only one here, we're many.

> There certainly are a lot of letters on this page alone, and many many more elsewhere.

I'm just existing in daily life, but I'm not living.

> Letters are everywhere, but are not alive.

My name is composed by 6 letters.

> L E T T E R

I can be big like I can be small.

> Capital or lower-case.

A group of me and those similar to me can be composed by at maximum 27 different types.

> Well, 26 is less than 27, and no word in English can have more than 26 different types of letters.  Maybe 27 if you count hyphens or apostrophes?  (Though not both)

325-346

> This is the only clue I can't get to fit, so not sure what to do with it.

Comment: I had the same idea and also got stuck with that last clue... My logic for the '27' clue was [this (medium.com)](https://medium.com/@jonhudson.main/the-old-27th-letter-of-the-english-alphabet-d073c777db26)...

Comment: l'm sorry, but there is already a popular thing called "Letters alive".

Comment: Congratulations, you got this! :) Well, I'm sorry to say that I typed 27 instead of 26, anyway the last clue is composed by 2 numbers: the first is about how many letters there are in the answer, including the title, but excluding the phrase "Guess who I am", while the second includes this, too.

Comment: @xKobalt Huh.  Okay, I thought this was kind of a throwaway guess, especially since the answer appears in the title and one of the clues, but sometimes you get lucky.  I don't think I'd have gotten that last clue without a hint though.  Counting the letters is not something I'd have thought of doing normally.  Also, you counted wrong - the last phrase adds only 11 letters, but you added 21...

Answer (score 5):

Is it..

> dashes(plural though, which makes me question it) or maybe hyphen?

I can be the first like I can be the last, but I'm usually in the middle between.

> dashes can be the first or the last but usually in between.

I'm not the only one here, we're many.

> This makes me think about punctuation marks, bu cant really connect it to dashes.

I'm just existing in daily life, but I'm not living.

> Exists in daily life(the written language) but obviously not living.

My name is composed by 6 letters.

> D A S H E S or H Y P H E N

I can be big like I can be small

> dashes can be big or small(shorter or longer)

A group of me and those similar to me can be composed by at maximum 27 different types

> There are 3 types of dashes(em, en and the double hyphen). There are 14 commonly used punctuation marks according to a google search(but they do not separate "curly" brackets from "square" brackets etc. So maybe the total will add up to 27 different types.

325-346

> This one has a dash in between, which makes me think of "hint1"

Comment: This answer looks well argumented, except for the second clue, in fact, I appreciate this, too, but I'm afraid to say that is not the answer I thought for this riddle. (However it was a nice try, maybe next time will be the one right)

Answer (score 4):

Final Answer

> **WINDOW**

Because
I can be the first like I can be the last, but I'm usually in the middle between.

> First or last window on a building, usually in the middle of a wall

I'm not the only one here, we're many.

> Many windows

I'm just existing in daily life, but I'm not living.

> Seeing through a window during the day

My name is composed by 6 letters.

> W I N D O W

I can be big like I can be small.

> Windows can be big or small

A group of me and those similar to me can be composed by at maximum 27 different types.

> Found a site that said there are only 27 types of windows, will cite or link if needed

325-346

> Dunno about this one. 325-346 = -21, maybe a coldness rating for a window???

Previous Answer

> **TWELVE**

Comment: I'm afraid to say this is not the answer I expected, but at the same time I've really appreciated it, all corresponds perfectly, except for the last two clues: the first one is a nice hypotesis, think `Clocks and watches?` are clock/watches types, this link (https://watchranker.com/types-of-watches/) provides 27 types of watches you've to know, but however they are not going to be all; for the second one, I'm afraid you don't have found a real answer. Nice try, however :)

Comment: Nope. I didn't look anything up. That is a very coincidental link though. Like insanely coincidental. Saw the mistake for my final after I posted. Otherwise, I wouldn't have even answered.

Comment: @MacGyver88 , you produced backpuzzle -- when a gulp of puzzle returns another. Like backwash, in the positive sense.

Comment: @humn, I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @MacGyver88, you could make a new puzzle based on this answer.

Comment: @humn, Oh, I thought I broke something. lol. I would asume then backpuzzles are a common occurrence for this type of puzzle. :)

Comment: Indeed, @MacGyver88, a musician might call it resonance.  An artist might call it reflection.  And a lexicologist would come up with a better word..

Comment: Well, I'm afraid to say this again, but neither this answer is the one I expected, however, I appreciated this, too, all this time has sense. It's nice to see these efforts from a single person

Answer (score 4):

Is it...?

> NUMBER

I can be the first like I can be the last, but I'm usually in the middle between.

> A number can be from -∞ to ∞, but in general we use numbers that are in the middle

I'm not the only one here, we're many.

> Numbers are infinite

I'm just existing in daily life, but I'm not living.

> We see numbers everywhere, from time to the battery remaining on the phone, although numbers aren't living beings

My name is composed by 6 letters.

> N U M B E R

I can be big like I can be small.

> Numbers can be extremely big and small

A group of me and those similar to me can be composed by at maximum 27 different types.

> Leet for example replaces certain letters with digits. Looking online I've found that the following 15 letters can be represented in leet by a single digit or composite number: A,B,E,F,G,H,I,L,O,P,R,S,T,Y,Z. B and G can be represented also using the numbers 13 and 12, so the total count with the 10 single digits is 27

325-346

> Is this a mobile number? Also 325-346 = -21 is still a number

Comment: Good attempt, this shocked me because every single clue has got a perfect answer. But at the same time, I'm afraid to say that's not the answer

Comment: Thanks @xKobalt, but I've got to say that the second to last was stretched, maybe not in a general sense, but adding everything up to 27 probably was

Comment: I will remember that :)